# NLP - Named Entity Recognition

Tags: java, nlp, named-entity-recognition

What algorithm does Named Entity Recognition (NER) use? I mean how does it match and tag all the entities?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, There are lot of algorithm Named Entity Recognition but the most famous are
Conditional Random Field(CRF) Algorithm is used.

1. Stanford CoreNLP for Java
2. Spacy
3. NLTK

Another most effective one is using Deep Learning like Recurrent Neural Network (LSTM).

1. http://nlp.town/blog/ner-and-the-road-to-deep-learning/
2. https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-learning-for-ner-1-public-datasets-and-annotation- 
     methods-8b1ad5e98caf 
   there are lot other articles and paper out there 
   Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 2):

NER can be performed by different algorithms, from simple string matching using grep: http://labs.fc.ul.pt/mer/ to advanced machine learning techniques: https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Basically, It Depends on the approach that you are following.

For Name Entity Recognition There are **n** no.of approaches available. Most typically **Conditional Random Field(CRF)** Algorithm is used. Another most effective one is using Deep Learning like **Recurrent Neural Network (LSTM)**. There might be other algorithms as well.

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play around with a nice, pre-built Bidirectional CRF-LSTM (currently one of the better performing models) in Keras, I would recommend the python package [Anango](https://github.com/Hironsan/anago) as a very quick way to play around with an NER system.

Although this initial question is tagged with Java. It is important to point out that you are going to find all the latest and greatest algorithms for this type of Machine Learning implemented in Python.

*Spacy* (a Python package) is also a very good way to get started although I found it took a little more time to set something up quickly. Also, I'm not sure how easy it would be to alter their NER algorithm that is pre-built. I believe it uses CNNs.

A good overview of where things are at with NER:
[A Survey on Recent Advances in Named Entity Recognition from Deep
Learning models](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C18-1182)